# How to get the program path i am executing with "open with" method?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I have the problem that i am using relative paths for my files, so when i use "open with" method for opening a file into my program, all my paths are screwed (it will create my files in the folder where i used this "open with" method.)

How i can retrieve the full path to the .exe file that im using to open the file with "open with" method?

**Edit:** my main function:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE   hInstance,          // Instance
                    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,      // Previous Instance
                    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,          // Command Line Parameters
                    int         nCmdShow)           // Window Show State
{
```

Comment: My guess is that you're using some kind of framework, not writing C++ Windows apps to the raw Windows API. Which one? It'll matter to the answer. (If you *are* writing it completely on your own, it's `argv[0]` in your `main` function.)

Comment: indeed :/ i updated my main function, i didnt see any other argument than the commandline there...and that doesnt even strip the quotes out of the filenames, i had to strip that myself... maybe i try to use SDL main, but i would like to know if there is possibility to do this on WINAPI winmain() too.

Comment: Beware. You really shouldn't be creating files in the folder where your EXE lives. You should treat that folder as read-only; although it's been true since Windows NT, the OS has enforced it more strictly with each new Windows version. Use the temporary directory (GetTempPath) or the "Application Settings" directory (SHGetFolderName) so admins don't have to make special exceptions when they install your program.

Comment: @Newbie: In the actual, true, lowest-level `main` (literally, that's the name of the function; `WinMain` is a different thing), the arguments are `int argc, char * argv[]` and `argv[0]` will be the executable's path. But (refreshed failing memory) it isn't guaranteed to be normalized, so that's no use to you -- unlike the two actually *useful* answers below. :-)

Comment: "You really shouldn't be creating files in the folder where your EXE lives" Then how im supposed to create some data files that should be easily copied by my users? like maps etc... im not gonna put them in the labyrith of windows paths, i hate finding those paths. each windows version has its own paths. and when you reinstall windows, you lose everything, but if the files are in the program folder, you wont lose them (supposing that you dont install the program in the windows partition...)

Comment: Provide a "save as" dialog box and ask the user where he or she wants you to put his or her map. Default to "My Documents." Why should the user *copy* the file when your program could put the *original* file exactly where it's needed?

Comment: because i want my program files to be in the directory i install, not cluttered all around my harddrive local files, my documents, or other folders like that. when i have 20 of such programs, and i want to reinstall windows, what do i do? i go through all those sub folders in my documents and decide which files to copy and where and why? yes sure... have fun wasting your time, because im not going to do that. ever since windows invented such folders, ive noticed they are nothing but a problem to the users. all i hear is whining "where are my files!?" and"omg i lost all my files!",so no thanks.

Comment: Your premise was that the "Program Files" folder was on a separate partition from the OS. If that's the case, then why wouldn't the "Documents and Settings" folder *also* be separate from the OS? If you're keeping programs separate, keep your personal files separate, too. Re-installing Windows doesn't delete your personal files (even if they *are* on the same drive). Why would you need to choose which files from My Documents you'd need to copy? Copy them all — they're *your* documents. When you store personal files in a program directory, *then* you have a problem knowing what's worth keeping.

Comment: Yeah the problem is i dont want to copy 20 gigs of stuff... and maps arent that personal really. If its some chatting program, then  of course i would use such protected folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

string ExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    if ( pos == string::npos ) {
        return "";
    else {
        return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "executable path is " << ExePath() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx) will give you the absolute path of your executable:

```
wchar_t executablePath[MAX_PATH];
if(GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, executablePath, MAX_PATH) == 0) { ... error ... }
else { ... find out executable path and set cwd ... }
```